# Transaction to a linked server causes error: viperrm.cpp:1780 in Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I try to send update to a linked server that goes like that:

```
begin transaction
SET XACT_ABORT ON
update LINKEDServer.mydb.DBO.MyTable set ....
```

I get:

```
Location:    viperrm.cpp:1780
Expression:  !m_irm && !m_idtm && !m_rmSink && !m_tmAddress && !m_iti && !m_ittf && !m_itrf
SPID:        53
Process ID:  5760
Msg 21, Level 20, State 1, Line 4
Ostrzeżenie: W obiekcie X 17 2022  9:40AM wystąpił błąd krytyczny 3624. Zanotuj treść i godzinę wystąpienia błędu, a następnie skontaktuj się z administratorem systemu.
Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 0
Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

There is some problem with transaction. In linked server I have set option to "true" to promote transaction. On other servers the problem doesn't occur.

Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31) (KB5016884) - 14.0.3456.2 (X64)   Sep  2 2022 11:01:50   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: )

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Removed screenshot.

Comment: This is an internal error, not a whole lot you (or anyone else) can do other than verify that your remote server is fully up to date as well (not just your origin server).

Comment: Is it possible to report bug somewhere? Is it online support for bugs etc ...? Sql server forum for bugs ...

Comment: This is unlikely a bug, but unfortunately probably not an easy issue to diagnose. Do you have the [MSDTC (Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator)](https://sqltimes.wordpress.com/2017/01/28/sql-server-what-is-msdtc-and-is-it-required/) enabled on your servers?

Answer (score 0):

Instance reinstallation solved the issue.